# how to pass form data from screen1 to screen2 in react native?

Tags: react-native

how to pass form data from screen1 to screen2 in react native ? I have following code in scrren1 I want posted amount data in screen2. Please let me know how can I pass data on screen2 and receive it in react native?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native'; // 0.6.9
const Form = t.form.Form;
const User = t.struct({
  amount: t.String,
});
const formStyles = {
  ...Form.stylesheet,
  formGroup: {
    normal: {
      marginBottom: 10
    },
  },
  controlLabel: {
    normal: {
      color: 'blue',
      fontSize: 18,
      marginBottom: 7,
      fontWeight: '600'
    },
    // the style applied when a validation error occours
    error: {
      color: 'red',
      fontSize: 18,
      marginBottom: 7,
      fontWeight: '600'
    }
  }
}
const options = {
  fields: {
    amount: {
      label: "Enter Amount You want to Top up",
      error: 'Please add amount to proceed ahead!'
    },
  },
  stylesheet: formStyles,
};
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    console.log('value: ', value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form 
          ref={c => this._form = c}
          type={User} 
          options={options}
        />
        <Button
          title="Pay Now"
          onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
});
export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: one way is to pass data from parent (Screen 1) to child (Screen 2) using props

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to pass data between Parent to Child, Child to Parent or Between Siblings

I suggest you to read [Passing Data Between React Components](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17), old but this article did help me to understand the logic behind passing data as it's not as easy to implement as in other programming languages.

Excerpt using props:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
    [... somewhere in here I define a variable listName 
     which I think will be useful as data in my ToDoList component...]

        return (
            <div>
                 <InputBar/>
                 <ToDoList listNameFromParent={listName}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now in the ToDoList component, use this.props.listNameFromParent to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to send informations from one screen to another in React Native. 
**eg.**

- Use **React Navigation** to navigate between your scenes. You will be able to pass params to your components, which will be accessible in the navigation props when received.

  `this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'sceneOne', params:{name} });`
- You can also send directly props to a component, and treat them in it. In your *render* section of your first component, you could have something like this :

`<myComponent oneProps={name}/>`

In that example, you will receive the props "oneProps" in your second component and you will be able to access it that way :

```
type Props = {
   oneProps: string,
}

class myComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
   render() {
     console.log('received sent props', oneProps);
     return (
       <View> // display it
         <Text>{this.props.oneProps}</Text>
       </View>
     );
   };
 }
```

These are only two effective solutions, but there are a lot more.

Hope it helped you :)

Have a good day